# Updating ADT - Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

Updating my SDK using SDK manager caused errors to all my projects in workspace. It shows a box shown like below.

[image]

and I downloaded ADT.23.0.4. and added the zip file by Help > Install new software. But after shown downloaded tools.I am not able to finish it.What is this error conflict dependency? Please help.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.feature.group 23.0.4.1468518)
Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer 23.0.4.1468518)
Hierarchy Viewer 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: ADT Package 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
To: com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 22.2.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Android Developer Tools 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [22.3.0.v201310242005-887826]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Android Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.4.1468518 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.feature.group 23.0.4.1468518)
To: com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer [23.0.4.1468518]
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Android Hierarchy Viewer 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826)
To: com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer [22.3.0.v201310242005-887826]
```

Answer (score 0):

@paypaluser please download zip file of adt from [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

and install using eclipse menu Help-->Install new software.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can go to the Software when it is asking; see there is highlighted already installed? in blue color click that or

2) Uninstall the Android ADT Package and then make sure important :("You don't restart the Eclipse ") then follow the same procedure and install new software

It works! I had the same problem now its O.K

Regards
Shezan Developer